# why jquery is blocked in https ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, https

I got a problem when i go on my website with https. The CDN of jquery is blocked.
Here is the message send in console `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://eoxys-esport.com/?here=home' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

The website works when i am in http.

Comment: load `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`

Comment: it is expected that when you are using any secure domain using `HTTPS` any call to other domain will be secure calling like `https`, not HTTP. you just change you jquery `cdn` protocol to 'https` it will work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to load the jQuery script from a secured HTTPS protocol.
Just use `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js` and the error should be gone. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

It's always best to load scripts and/or css from CDN's using `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>` without `https:` or `http:` as then based on the protocol you are on, the correct CDN protocol will be used. Cause if you hardcode `https:` you will get the same errors when the page requesting the CDN file is on `http:`